# How can I configure TCP keepAliveTimeout for DB2's JDBC Driver?

Tags: java, jdbc, db2, db2-luw

[This page](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21984958) suggests I can tune the `keepAliveTimeout` value manually for DB2 with JDBC.

This [list of driver properties that I've found](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.java.doc/src/tpc/imjcc_r0052075.html) doesn't mention this setting.

This [other list of JDBC and SQLJ propeties](http://propertieshttps://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.java.doc/src/tpc/imjcc_r0052038.html) mentions the `keepAliveTimeOut`setting. However, it also says

> Unless otherwise noted, all properties are in com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2BaseDataSource.

How do I do that? As I understand it, these settings are distinct from the DB2 connect string settings, otherwise the aforementioned list would also mention the `currentSchema` setting.

[Yet another page suggests](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.ha.doc/doc/t0058766.html) I need a file called  `db2dsdriver.cfg` but this does not seem to be applicable to JDBC according to [this list](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.config.doc/doc/c0054555.html).

How do I actually configure `keepAliveTimeout` for JDBC and check that it's active and set to whatever I've configured?

Comment: Did you come up with any solution to this? I am in a very similar situation

Comment: @Alpay Unfortunately not, no.

Answer (score 1):

I see that you must specify `keepAliveTimeout=0` in connection string and if you use 0 as value jdbc does't use internal value but it will use the operating systema value for interval time.

I found that here:

- https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/keepalive-parameters-jdbc-driver
- https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/tcpip-keepalive-settings-and-related-db2-registry-variables